# Android: Create Horizontal List View but Image size cannot be set

Tags: android, listview, view, viewgroup, horizontallist

I'd like to create an Horizontal List View.
And I reference this http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

But it set ImageView size 150dp in "listitem.xml"

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="150dip"
      android:layout_height="150dip"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/icon"
      />
```

I tried to change the width and height of the ImageView, but it's useless.

It seems that in the HorizontalListView.java, the function "addAndMeasureChild()" has set

```
child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
```

But I change the MEasureSpec to EXACTLY or others, it's still useless.

Anyone can figure out this?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Comment: I have the same problem...any answers?

Answer (score 0):

MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth()... is the width of the listview, try replacing getWidth() with params.width, this worked for me using a fixed size for the layout, in your case, the imageview. My solution doesn't work if you use MATCH_PARENT or WRAP_CONTENT.